# SXA: Image with external link not working

Tags: sxa

Using SXA 1.2 rev. 161216, I am not able to click on an image's external link even when I specified one in it's URL field.

How to enable it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to edit the **Image.cshtml** view and change the following condition,

```
@if (Model.LinkItem != null && Model.LinkItem.TargetItem != null)
```

for

```
@if (Model.LinkItem != null && (Model.LinkItem.TargetItem != null || (!Model.LinkItem.IsInternal && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LinkItem.TargetUrl))))
```

as a matter of fact, in case there is an external link, the LinkItem.TargetItem is null and we need to get into this piece of code and in the case there is no specified link, we need to avoid getting in the code because it would render a link to this page (thank you guschti !)

Comment: If you just remove the second condition, also images with no explicitly set link will render with a link tag referencing the current page. I'd suggest to extend the condition as follows: `@if (Model.LinkItem != null && (Model.LinkItem.TargetItem != null || (!Model.LinkItem.IsInternal && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.LinkItem.TargetUrl))))`